# sql 2000: static ports for multiple sql server 2000 instances on same server

Tags: sql-server

For multiple instances of SQL server 2000 servers on the same server, how can I set up to use static ports? I tried to search it on the Internet and i came across [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294453/) article. If I use this article, how will assign port number for seperate instances?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

solved. One of my friends answered:

Start the Server Network Utility. To do this, do one of the following:
Click Start, point to Programs, point to Microsoft SQL Server, and then click Server Network Utility.

In the Instance(s) on this server list, select your instance of SQL Server.

In the Default port box, type a static port number, and then click OK.

Note The static port that you specify must differ from the dynamic port that your instance of SQL Server is currently listening on. 
Restart the instance of SQL Server.
From:
[This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823938)